# Segmentation Fault when checking if a node is empty in C

Tags: c

I have a function called isNull(), it checks whether the given node is SYSNULL, SYSNULL is essentially a pointer to null, not exactly important. When I call this function in a while loop from another function, I get a seg fault. The reason that I was told when asked was that I haven't dereferenced the pointer, node_ptr, yet. How do I dereference the pointer? And if that's not the issue, then how do I fix it? I've provided the code for the 2 functions, everything compiles without warning/error. Help would be greatly appreciated.

isNull:

```
int isNull(struct system *system, int *node_ptr) {

  if(*node_ptr == SYSNULL) {
    return 1;
  }
  else {
    return 0;
  }


}
```

appendItem:

```
void appendItem(struct system *system, struct List *list, void *src) {

  int i;
  int svoid = isEmpty(system, list);
  while(svoid != 1) {
    next(system, &i); //Calls a function that goes to next node.
    i++;
  }

}
```

next:

```
int next(struct system *system, int *node_ptr) {

  struct Node *head = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
  struct Node *newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

  if(head == NULL) {
    printf("List is empty");
    exit(0);
  }
  else {
    newNode->next = *node_ptr;
    return newNode->next;
  }
  free(head);
  free(newNode);

}
```

Comment: If there is no pointer in the `List` struct, this is not a linked list. I would recommend to start with the fundamentals before throwing more code at it.

Comment: @thomas the struct is what we were provided with. Would you happen to know how to dereference the pointer in my isNull function?

Comment: I'm having trouble imagining a situation where *not* dereferencing a pointer is the reason for a segfault.  They are far more likely to arise from dereferencing a pointer that one ought not to have dereferenced.

Comment: Incidentally, dereferencing a pointer is using the `*` or `[]` or `->` operator to access the thing it points to.

Comment: It is hard to help you out if we don't know what you are trying to do. To know if there is something wrong with `IsNull`, we need to know how it is called, and how `SYSNULL` is defined. (and why are you passing the unused parameter `system`?) Other than that, you are reading the content of the uninitialized variable `i` in `appendItem`.  `svoid` never changes its value, so the loop might go forever. `next` doesn't do anything useful, except leaking memory like a sieve, and potentially dereferencing a NULL-pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The `*node_ptr` you are comparing to `SYSNULL` is an `int`, not a pointer.
The pointer would be `node_ptr`, if that is NULL, then dereferencing it as you do could explain the segfault.

Quoting John Bollingers comment (assuming it is OK):

> And if you turn up your compiler's warning level, yet it still fails to at least emit a warning about this, then you should find a better compiler.

Comment: And if you turn up your compiler's warning level, yet it still fails to at least emit a warning about this, then you should find a better compiler.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I assume that you are fine with having your comment contribution incorporated into my answer. (I think I asked you in similar situations....).

Comment: Sure, no objection